# SOAP Request fails with "Invalid service URL" error

Tags: web-services, blackberry, rim-4.5

My BlackBerry application consumes axis2 web services. SOAP POST HTTP request constantly fails with this error "Invalid service URL". I launch my app in  8800 simulator with ";deviceside=false" option specified. MDS is running.

I can't test my app on real device for now. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. You need to add specific options to MDS configuration to make it work behind proxy. Here's an artical that describes the [solution](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800738/800792/801079/How_To_-_Configure_the_MDS_simulator_to_work_behind_a_proxy.html?nodeid=800740&vernum=4).